# Why does OHG wedar have "e"?

Tags: germanic-languages, proto-germanic

Why does OHG w**e**dar from PGmc *hw**a**þeraz have "e"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are two different ablaut grades: IE *-tero- versus *-toro-.

Comment: Wrong syllable – the question is about the _e_ in the first syllable of _wedar_: PIE _*kʷo-(t-)_ > PWGmc. _*hwaþ-_ > OHG _w**e**d-_. In fact, it becomes _e_ [pretty much everywhere in West Germanic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/hwaþar), with OE being the only language to show the intermediate stage _æ_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The ablaut affects both parts: *kwe : *kwo- and *-tero- : *toro-

Comment: No it doesn’t. The PIE form is uniformly [_*kʷóteros_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/kʷóteros) in all branches, not _**kʷéteros_ or _**kʷótoros_. And even if there were such a variation within PIE, it is completely unthinkable that the individual languages that developed from Proto-West-Germanic suddenly decided to make productive use of ablaut in this one word (for absolutely no reason). Ablaut was a fossilised system by then, only systematically discernible in strong verbs.

Comment: also this is a thematic adjective, and thematic adjectives famously exhibit no ablaut between different forms within the paradigm. Unless you're suggesting it's an _athematic_ o-stem that somehow retained this truly exceptional declension as late as the breakup of Proto-West-Germanic which is such an extraodinary claim we'd need a lot more evidence than some unexplained raising of one vowel from a to e

Comment: also also, ablaut affecting multiple syllables like that, e.g. *kʷeter- vs *kʷotor- (ignoring the thematic/athematic issue, and the position of the accent for now) would also be truly extraordinary. This is far beyond special pleading and not remotely plausible as an explanation unless you have some superb evidence in your back pocket

Comment: @Tristan I trust you have looked at Pfeifer; https://www.dwds.de/wb/weder

Comment: @fdb it doesn't look like he provides any justification for claiming such an anomalous ablaut in the section quoted there, so that doesn't even remotely suffice as justification

Comment: FWIW, Kroonen in his Germanic etymological dictionary doesn't comment on the ablaut of kʷo at all, but does point to PIE kʷo-t(e/o)r-o- and compares with Skt. katará-, Av. katāra-. The Sanskrit must derive from the typical -ter-o-, but the Avestan shows the affects of Brugmann's Law so must point to a -tor-o- form. Nonetheless, as there is no hint of an athematic declension here we must interpret these as two parallel thematic adjectives, one in -ter- and the other in -tor- not as paradigmatic ablaut. And again there is no possibility of this e/o ablaut in both initial and second syllable

Comment: @AlexB. I can’t really satisfactorily explain the WG _e_ here. It’s a very good question. My best guess is that it’s an extreme case of Anglo-Frisian brightening that somehow made its way outside Anglo-Frisian. This only works if the PWG form was _*hwaþer_, of course (not _*hwaþar_ as Wiktionary has it), but then I’m not sure why Wiktionary thinks PG _*-þer-_ should become PWG _*-þar_ here, only to then become _*-þer_ again almost everywhere; it seems more economic to assume that it remained _*-þer-_ in general, but was assimilated or lowered in a few individual languages.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thank you! FYI, as for the ablaut hypothesis in this case, it’s not that completely unheard of, see e.g. https://books.google.com/books?id=7-05DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA928&dq=OHG+wedar+ablaut&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLxbClkruEAxXkOjQIHe38DwoQ6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=OHG%20wedar%20ablaut&f=false

Comment: @AlexB. Also Mayrhofer's entry on katara-.